# The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing Dotnet API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I try to hit an api request (Post Method) using dotnet web api but find the below error so, what is the solution for this problem?

```
System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The request was canceled due to the configured HttpClient.Timeout of 100 seconds elapsing.
 ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation was canceled.
 ---> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
 ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request..
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (995): The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<System.Int32>.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EnsureFullTlsFrameAsync[TIOAdapter](CancellationToken cancellationToken, Int32 estimatedSize)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReadAsyncInternal[TIOAdapter](Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.InitialFillAsync(Boolean async)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFailure(Exception e, Boolean telemetryStarted, HttpResponseMessage response, CancellationTokenSource cts, CancellationToken cancellationToken, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts, CancellationTokenSource pendingRequestsCts, CancellationToken originalCancellationToken)
   at DeployEmployeesInfo.Controllers.AxantiaEmployeesInfoController.getDate() in D:\MyFiles\RAR Extracted Files\DeployEmployeesInfo\DeployEmployeesInfo\Controllers\AxantiaEmployeesInfoController.cs:line 114
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

## HEADERS

Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br, zstd
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0
Host: localhost:44304
Referer: https://localhost:44304/swagger/index.html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="122", "Not(A:Brand";v="24", "Google Chrome";v="122"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
origin: https://localhost:44304
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty

I try increase time out and cancellation token but it didn't worked.

Comment: Perhaps the error is correct and the server didn't respond in 100s ? Increasing the timeout won't help if the server doesn't respond, or if it's frozen by a debugger

Comment: What does `AxantiaEmployeesInfoController.getDate()` do? Something in there is making a call that times out. Please post the method's code.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think you are right but what do you mean by 'frozen by a debugger'?

Comment: could you please share some code which is causing this issue?have you tried adding this code: `_httpClient = new HttpClient
{
    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
};`  also try to increase the `MaxConnectionsPerServer`.